# How to find largest number in a permutation in python?

Tags: python, math, permutation, finite-group-theory

I want to extract the highest number from a permutation. I am using the groups module right now so the output in the below code should be 15

```
from groups import *

a = Perm((1, 2, 3), (4, 15, 6), (7, 8, 9))

max([x for x in a])
```

Comment: what does the permutation has to do with the max number here?

Comment: well I need to find the max of a much larger permutation. That is just an example

Comment: @NewYork But a permutation doesn't change the max number

Comment: so how do I find the max number if given a permutation?

Comment: I am unable to find any module named `groups` in conda or in PyPI or in a quick web search. Where did you get this module and where is its documentation? There are many possible implementations of permutation groups, and the particular implementation matters for your question.

Comment: Here is a file I found online https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7042.pdf

Comment: @RoryDaulton see the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to define the maximum of a permutation:

```
p = permutations([1, 2, 3])
l = list(p)
max(l[0])
```

and then iterate over the given permutations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting exactly what you want this these permutation, if only want to find the maximum.But you try this-

```
    from itertools import permutations 
    perm = permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
    for i in list(perm): 
    print (max(i))
```

This piece of code will always 15 as output.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not creating your permutation correctly. The correct syntax, best seen on page 23 in [your link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7042.pdf), is

```
a = Perm()(1, 2, 3)(4, 15, 6)(7, 8, 9)
```

Next, that module is set up so that theoretically it permutes all non-negative integers, with finitely many of them mapping to values other than themselves. So theoretically there is no highest number in a permutation in that module. As your link states on page 5,

> The perm size *n* is undeﬁned because keys not deﬁned explicitly are equal to their values (*p[i] == i*).

So in one respect your quest to "extract the highest number from a permutation" is meaningless. However, at any given time, the data structure representing a permutation in that module does have a largest number. The module tries to hide that information from the user, to keep the theoretical viewpoint of acting on all non-negative integers. But since the `Perm` class is derived from the `dict` built-in type, you can find the current highest number in that structure with

```
highestnum = max(a)
```

In your example, that does return the value `15`. But be aware that the largest value could easily change, without changing the permutation that is being represented. For example, if you execute `print(a[20])`, that does not seem to change the permutation `a`, and comparing the value of `a` to its previous value using `==` yields `True`. But now `max(a)` yields the value `20`. Thus `max(a)` is not consistent and depends on the current internal representation of the permutation, so it is not wise to use this value.

Fortunately, you can find a more consistent "highest number", namely the highest number that is changed by the permutation:

```
highestnum = a.max()
```

This also returns the result you want, `15`. Accessing `a[20]` or any other value does not change `a.max()`, so you should satisfy yourself with the `max()` value.

By the way, regarding your linked document, here is [a better link](http://ojs.pythonpapers.org/index.php/tpp/article/viewFile/258/229) to the documentation, which is a finished version of the pre-print you linked to. And here is [a link to the source code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/perms-dict/source/default/source). However, I referred to your link in what I wrote above. The Python code in that document uses Python 2.6: I made some changes so it runs in Python 3.7 and used that to check my answer.